# sed conditionally append to line after matching pattern

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I've a file (test) with the following content which needs to edited.

**test**

```
foo:
bar:hello
```

I'm currently using sed to match a pattern and append a string to the end of line.

```
sed -ie "/^bar/ s/$/,there" test
```

Which is giving me the expected output i.e.

```
foo:
bar:hello,there
```

But the issue is, that comma (,) should be there when the line is not ending in `:`. else it becomes like:

```
sed -ie "/^foo/ s/$/,there" test
```

**Output:**

```
foo:,there
bar:hello
```

**Requirement:**

```
foo:there
bar:hello
```

So is it possible by any means to check for a pattern, after matching check the last character of the line, depending on the last character, append a string to the end of the line.

P.S.: I can't install a separate package.

Comment: If you want to append "there" to the line "foo:", then why check for "bar" at all?

Comment: that "foo" or "bar" comes as a input. So i'm receiving it in a variable and using that variable inside sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using `t` after a successful substitution to branch away from a second `s///` command:

```
$ cat test
foo:
bar:
bar:hello
bar:
bar:hello
bar:
bar:hello

$ sed '/^bar/ {s/:$/:there/;t;s/$/, there/}' test 
foo:
bar:there
bar:hello, there
bar:there
bar:hello, there
bar:there
bar:hello, there
```

Answer (score 4):

Keep it simple and just use awk:

```
$ awk '/^foo/{$0 = $0 (/:$/ ? "" : ",") "there"} 1' file
foo:there
bar:hello

$ awk '/^bar/{$0 = $0 (/:$/ ? "" : ",") "there"} 1' file
foo:
bar:hello,there
```

Notice how all of the original string (`foo` or `bar`), the `:`, the `,`, the `$`, and the replacement text (`there`) are all only specified once? That's one of the things you want in software - minimal redundancy.

The above will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Comment: though the answer is simpler than sed, awk has extra work to write the changes to the same file while with sed it's easier.

Comment: @RatDon just like GNU sed has `-i`, GNU awk has `-i inplace` to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The patterns in front of your sed commands are your conditions.  You should be aware that you can specify multiple -e commands for sed.

Here's your code again, but I'm ignoring foo and bar.   I am only paying attention to the last character:

```
sed -i -e '/[^:]$/s/$/,there/' -e '/:$/s/$/there/' test
```

/[^:]$/ is any character that is not a colon at the end of the line.  /:$/ is it's complement (any line ending with colon).

Here are the results:

```
$ sed  -e '/[^:]$/s/$/,there/' -e '/:$/s/$/there/' test
foo:there
bar:hello,there
```

Answer (score 0):

try gnu sed for both,

```
sed -E '/^(foo|bar)/ s/:$/&there/;n; s/[^:]$/&,there/' test
```